# Best dataframe extraction method from multilevel XML

Tags: r, xml

does anyone know the best way to extract data into dataframe from multilevel XML from this example: http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml

As_tibble doesn't work because it has stop supporting unnamed columns and I couldn't figure out a good alternative. I am new to R. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For complex, nested documents and attributes with default namespaces consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML documents such as flattening them for migration into R data frames. R can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with the `xslt` package (extension of `xml2`).

Below extracts all information under `<Race>` nodes. Should `<ResultsList>` extend beyond one `<Result>` per `<Race>`, a different XSLT approach will be required where you drill down to each `<Result>` element and retrieve `ancestor` (rather than `descendant`) nodes that will repeat for every unique `<Result>`.

**XSLT**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:doc="http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="doc:Race">
     <xsl:copy>
          <!-- RETRIEVE ALL ATTRIBUTES -->
          <xsl:for-each select="@*|descendant::*[@*]/@*">
              <xsl:element name="{concat(name(..), '_', name())}" 
                           namespace="http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>

          <!-- RETRIEVE ALL ELEMENTS -->
          <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[text()]">
              <xsl:element name="{concat(name(..), '_', name())}" 
                           namespace="http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
              </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4uw)</kbd>

**R**

```r
library(xml2)
library(xslt)

# LOAD XML AND XSL
doc <- read_xml("http://ergast.com/api/f1/1954/results/1.xml")
style <- read_xml("/path/to/Flatten/Script.xsl", package = "xslt")

# RUN TRANSFORMATION
new_xml <- xml_xslt(doc, style)

# RETRIEVE Race NODES
nmsp <- c(doc = "http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4")
recs <- xml2::xml_find_all(new_xml, "//doc:Race", ns=nmsp)

# BIND EACH CHILD TEXT AND NAME
df_list <- lapply(recs, function(r) {
  vals <- xml2::xml_children(r)
  
  data.frame(rbind(setNames(c(xml2::xml_text(vals)), 
                            c(xml2::xml_name(vals)))))
})

# COMBINE ALL DFS
ergast_races_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, df_list)
rm(recs, df_list)
```

**Output**

```r
str(ergast_races_df)
# 'data.frame': 9 obs. of  32 variables:
#   $ Race_season              : chr  "1954" "1954" "1954" "1954" ...
#   $ Race_round               : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#   $ Race_url                 : chr  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_Argentine_Grand_Prix" "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_Indianapolis_500" "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_Belgian_Grand_Prix" "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_French_Grand_Prix" ...
#   $ Circuit_circuitId        : chr  "galvez" "indianapolis" "spa" "reims" ...
#   $ Circuit_url              : chr  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aut%C3%B3dromo_Oscar_Alfredo_G%C3%A1lvez" "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indianapolis_Motor_Speedway" "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_de_Spa-Francorchamps" "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reims-Gueux" ...
#   $ Location_lat             : chr  "-34.6943" "39.795" "50.4372" "49.2542" ...
#   $ Location_long            : chr  "-58.4593" "-86.2347" "5.97139" "3.93083" ...
#   $ Result_number            : chr  "2" "14" "26" "18" ...
#   $ Result_position          : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
#   $ Result_positionText      : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
#   $ Result_points            : chr  "8" "8" "9" "8" ...
#   $ Driver_driverId          : chr  "fangio" "vukovich" "fangio" "fangio" ...
#   $ Driver_url               : chr  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_Manuel_Fangio" "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Vukovich" "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_Manuel_Fangio" "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_Manuel_Fangio" ...
#   $ Constructor_constructorId: chr  "maserati" "kurtis_kraft" "maserati" "mercedes" ...
#   $ Constructor_url          : chr  "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maserati" "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtis_Kraft" "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maserati" "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercedes-Benz_in_Formula_One" ...
#   $ Status_statusId          : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
#   $ Time_millis              : chr  "10855800" "13757270" "9882400" "9767900" ...
#   $ Race_RaceName            : chr  "Argentine Grand Prix" "Indianapolis 500" "Belgian Grand Prix" "French Grand Prix" ...
#   $ Circuit_CircuitName      : chr  "Autódromo Juan y Oscar Gálvez" "Indianapolis Motor Speedway" "Circuit de Spa-Francorchamps" "Reims-Gueux" ...
#   $ Location_Locality        : chr  "Buenos Aires" "Indianapolis" "Spa" "Reims" ...
#   $ Location_Country         : chr  "Argentina" "USA" "Belgium" "France" ...
#   $ Race_Date                : chr  "1954-01-17" "1954-05-31" "1954-06-20" "1954-07-04" ...
#   $ Driver_GivenName         : chr  "Juan" "Bill" "Juan" "Juan" ...
#   $ Driver_FamilyName        : chr  "Fangio" "Vukovich" "Fangio" "Fangio" ...
#   $ Driver_DateOfBirth       : chr  "1911-06-24" "1918-12-13" "1911-06-24" "1911-06-24" ...
#   $ Driver_Nationality       : chr  "Argentine" "American" "Argentine" "Argentine" ...
#   $ Constructor_Name         : chr  "Maserati" "Kurtis Kraft" "Maserati" "Mercedes" ...
#   $ Constructor_Nationality  : chr  "Italian" "American" "Italian" "German" ...
#   $ Result_Grid              : chr  "3" "19" "1" "1" ...
#   $ Result_Laps              : chr  "87" "200" "36" "61" ...
#   $ Result_Status            : chr  "Finished" "Finished" "Finished" "Finished" ...
#   $ Result_Time              : chr  "3:00:55.8" "3:49:17.27" "2:44:42.4" "2:42:47.9" ...
```